# Setting up Tor as a Transparent Proxy

Tags: proxy, iptables, tor

I have been following this guide at [Tor Project](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy).

The problem is I do not know what to do with the iptables ruleset. Where do I copy it to? I've been using the Tor network for years now but only on Tails. I am new to modifying Tor stuff and to iptables.

iptables ruleset:

```
#!/bin/sh

### set variables
#destinations you don't want routed through Tor
_non_tor="192.168.1.0/24 192.168.0.0/24"

#the UID that Tor runs as (varies from system to system)
_tor_uid="109"

#Tor's TransPort
_trans_port="9040"

### flush iptables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

### set iptables *nat
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53

#allow clearnet access for hosts in $_non_tor
for _clearnet in $_non_tor 127.0.0.0/9 127.128.0.0/10; do
   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_clearnet -j RETURN
done

#redirect all other output to Tor's TransPort
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

### set iptables *filter
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#allow clearnet access for hosts in $_non_tor
for _clearnet in $_non_tor 127.0.0.0/8; do
   iptables -A OUTPUT -d $_clearnet -j ACCEPT
done

#allow only Tor output
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
```

**EDIT:**

I did some searching and read that I could run `sudo iptables-save > iptables.conf` then replace the info in iptables.conf with the Tor iptables ruleset then run `iptables-restore < iptables.conf` but that prompted with an error saying

> iptables-restore: line 5 failed

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is just one of many possible ways:

Put that script file anywhere. For example mine is at `/home/doug/init/doug_firewall`.

Make sure the permissions are correct for execution. For example mine:

```
$ ls -l /home/doug/init/doug_firewall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 doug doug 60254 Jul  3 09:52 /home/doug/init/doug_firewall
```

Then edit the `/etc/network/intrefaces` file to execute the script during startup. For example mine:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces file for smythies.com 2016.01.30
#       attempt to set local DNS herein, as the method
#       used with the old 12.04 server no longer works.
#
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
pre-up /home/doug/init/doug_firewall
dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1

# The primary interface (d-link PCI card)
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp

# Local network interface (uses built in ethernet port)
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
  address 192.168.111.1
  network 192.168.111.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.111.255
```